# How to transpose rows and columns in dataTable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to show my Data in rows not in columns. (tranposing) You can see my example here.

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkyxegnf)

In my example, my categories (name, position, office, extn. start date, salary) were fixed in columns. My data was shown in Rows. I want to fix rows with my categories. How can I do this?

Comment: try this .. http://jsfiddle.net/t73danpb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr ,thead{ display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
tbody{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Another way..
Use [Transpose-Table-jQuery-Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Transpose-Table-jQuery-Plugin.html)

Updated answer link : http://jsfiddle.net/t73danpb/4/

Comment: I really like this tweak. Obviously it does not work well with the default CSS, but a good starting point if you want a small table "flipped".

Comment: @davidkonrad updated my anwer. You can use Transpose-Table-jQuery-Plugin

Comment: Ooops! Thank you so much. But, your updated answer is not working when i want to search something.