# R: crosstalk::SharedData linked data with different format (wide/long), when tidyverse verbs don't work

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse, dt, crosstalk

Edit **TL;DR**
Using `crosstalk` package, I am searching for a way to link a graph that utilizes long format data (a line plot) with an interactive table with data in wide format so that each row in table corresponds to a line in the plot.

I am trying to link a DT table with a plotly graph. My trouble revolves around the fact that the graph needs data in long format, while the table would be in wide format. I probably got fixated on the tidyverse way of doing things. I will try to provide a minimal example of what I am trying to do and what I would like to obtain.

**Setup:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

# Wide format
df_test1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id1", "id2"),
  item1 = c(0, 4),
  item2 = c(3, 2),
  item3 = c(1, 4),
  item4 = c(3, 4),
  item5 = c(1, NA)
)

# Reshaped to long format
df_test2 <- 
  df_test1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = item1:item5, names_to = "item", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(item = as.factor(item)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = factor(as.character(value), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

**What I tried:**

```
sd1 <- SharedData$new(df_test1, key = ~id)

bscols(
  ggplotly(
    sd1$origData() %>%    # should be sd1, but returns error
      # reshaping
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = item1:item5, names_to = "item", values_to = "value") %>%
      dplyr::mutate(item = as.factor(item)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(value = factor(as.character(value), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"))) %>%
      # ploting
      ggplot(., aes(x = value, y = item, group = id)) + 
      geom_path() + 
      geom_point(aes(color = value), size = 3) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")), 
  tooltip = c("x", "y", "group"), height = 600, width = 300),     
  datatable(sd1)
)
```

Of course, this gives an output only because I used `sd1$origData()` instead of `sd1` that was needed for the crosstalk functionality. Using `sd1` would have thrown an error as tidyverse verbs don't work with R6 crosstalk objects. Anyway, this gives the desired output of graph and table but without the crosstalk functionality.

**What I hope to obtain:**

```
sd2 <- SharedData$new(df_test2, key = ~id)

bscols(
  ggplotly(
    # ploting
    ggplot(sd2, aes(x = value, y = item, group = id)) + 
    geom_path() + 
    geom_point(aes(color = value), size = 3) + 
    scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")),     
  tooltip = c("x", "y", "group"), height = 600, width = 300),    
  datatable(sd2)
)
```

This works ok for a minimal example of the crosstalk functionality I want, but I need the data in `DT::datatable` to be in wide format. As in the example points and paths (marks and traces) need to be linked to `id`, which should be unique for every row in a wide format. Also, I am hoping I find a solution in which all points and paths will be invisible before users click on the desired table row.
I am guessing I am going the wrong way about this and would probably need to do something I didn't think about. I read that now, in 2021, plotly API can use [wide data](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/)
formatting but haven't found any examples of how this would be achieved in R.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can transpose the datatable via JS (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441755/how-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-datatable-js) and [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Transpose-Table-jQuery-Plugin.html)) using [htmlwidgets::onRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59407468/is-it-possible-to-make-an-onfocus-function-for-the-datatable-search-bar-in-r-shi).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I think the challenge is that the key needs to be unique, which is an intrinsically different data structure than "tidy". Just flatten it out and use `plotly::add_lines()` for each layer. Annoying, but works.

Comment: I am happy that there is a method but I am still not certain about what you are suggesting. Maybe, when you have time, provide an answer to the small reproducible example I gave so I can accept it and others know the workaround in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to create **two** `SharedData` objects, one in wide and one in long format, and connect them by giving both objects the same group name in the `group` argument of `SharedData$new()`. See below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

# Wide format
df_test1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id1", "id2"),
  item1 = c(0, 4),
  item2 = c(3, 2),
  item3 = c(1, 4),
  item4 = c(3, 4),
  item5 = c(1, NA)
)

# Reshaped to long format
df_test2 <- 
  df_test1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = item1:item5, names_to = "item", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(item = as.factor(item)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = factor(as.character(value), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")))

# two shared data objects. Note the group argument. 
# this argument can be any string, as long as it is the same in both 
# datasets:
sd1 <- SharedData$new(df_test1, key = ~id, group = "groupdata")
sd2 <- SharedData$new(df_test2, key = ~id, group = "groupdata")

bscols(
  ggplotly(
      ggplot(sd2, aes(x = value, y = item, group = id)) + 
      geom_path() + 
      geom_point(aes(color = value), size = 3) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")), 
    tooltip = c("x", "y", "group"), height = 600, width = 300),     
  datatable(sd1)
)
```