# R: Plotly with wide-form data

Tags: r, plotly

Recently, the Plotly API (Plotly Express) for python was [updated to be able to handle wide data formatting](https://medium.com/plotly/beyond-tidy-plotly-express-now-accepts-wide-form-and-mixed-form-data-bdc3e054f891). A set of examples can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/).

I am a big fan of tidy data, so you may ask why I posted this question when `tidyr` exists.
My question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049109/r-crosstalkshareddata-linked-data-with-different-format-wide-long-when-tid) I have posted and remains unanswered. If there's a way to work with wide data in `Plotly.R` this would also be the solution for my other question.

For a minimal example, I would like to recreate the following [python `plotly.express` line plot](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KbYEzruOuuI2CVgt5z1kgb3wymcSt7PA?usp=sharing) in R.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Even partial or hacky solutions may aid me.